# FileNotFoundException although the file is exist

Tags: java, file, path, filenotfoundexception, randomaccessfile

I'm trying to get to some text file in my computer but I keep getting this exception although the path is correct and the file is exist.
Here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File wordFile = new File("‪D:\\IDC\\Stuff\\wordList.txt");
    RandomAccessFile wordsList = new RandomAccessFile(wordFile, "rw");

    System.out.println(wordFile.exists());


}
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: ‪D:\IDC\Stuff\wordList.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
at WordChecker.main(WordChecker.java:12)
```

Comment: Have you tried to print the absolute path of the wordFile with `System.out.println(wordFile.getAbsolutePath())`? If not, try to copy the output of the last statement in your file explorer to check that the path exists. Besides, have you checked that you have the permissions to read and write to the desired file?

Comment: My bet is on `"wordList.txt.txt"` as the real file name. @Ohad121 Have you checked that the name of your file is what you think it is? No hidden file extension?

Comment: Can you open the file in windows? Looks more like a windows error instead of file not found error.

Comment: I try this now but still the same. I jave permissions on the file because I created it and I'm the administrator of the computer. I tried to move the file to the project folder of the eclips, now I just write the file nae without the entire path like this"wordList.txt" and it create a new file every time I run the program instead of reading from it.

Answer (score 2):

When I copied your code and tried to save it in Eclipse. I got the below error

[image]

I concluded from this, although your path looks '‪D:\\IDC\\Stuff\\wordList.txt' but actually it is not.So what I did, **just type this line** `File file =new File("D:\\IDC\\Stuff\\wordList.txt");` **instead of copy it from your code**. *And it worked.* It seems you also copied it from somewhere and for encoding issue you are getting the problem.

One more point, you should use `System.getProperty("file.separator")` instead of \\ or / just like below

```
File wordFile = new File("‪D:" + System.getProperty("file.separator")
                + "IDC" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "Stuff"
                + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "wordList.txt");
```

> **file.separator**
>
> Character that separates components of a file path. This is "/" on UNIX and "\" on Windows.

Comment: Oh my, this is correct, there ***is*** an invisible character before ``D:\`` (which I think is `U+202A`).

Answer (score 0):

Can you rename the file? This can help if you copied the file name from another location and it had non-visible characters in it.